# Getting exception 'Object reference not set instance of an object' in App.xaml on line 'RootFrame.Language'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, localization, globalization, app.xaml

Currently i am working on globalization feature in windows phone 8 app. i am getting exception ('Object reference not set instance of an object') in App.xaml in following line.

```
RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(AppResources.ResourceLanguage);
```

in AppResources.Designer.cs the definition of ResourceLangauge i have written as following.

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to LeftToRight.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ResourceFlowDirection
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceFlowDirection", resourceCulture);
        }
    }       


    /// <summary>
    ///   Looks up a localized string similar to en-US.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ResourceLanguage
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceLanguage", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

Please give me suggession where and what i am doing wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be the ResourceManager.GetString is not able to find the string.

Comment: Yes Nilesh you are right, I have not written two keys in my AppResources.resx files keys are
ResourceLanguage en-US and
ResourceFlowDirection LeftToRight
i made these changes and code is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not written two keys in my AppResources.resx files keys are

```
ResourceFlowDirection   LeftToRight 
ResourceLanguage            en-US
```

i found this during debugging.

Comment: Please mark this answer as the accepted answer so the question will appear as solved in the timeline.